# What's difference between "varchar" and "text" type in PostgreSQL?

Tags: database, postgresql

All I know about differences of them is `varchar` has limit, and `text` is not. The [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/datatype-character.html) does not mention about this.

Is that really the only difference? No consideration about performance or etc?

Comment: This should really be migrated to [dba.se]. It has nothing to whatsoever with server administration.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The background of this is: The old Postgres system used the PostQUEL language and used a data type named `text` (because someone thought that was a good name for a type that stores text).  Then, Postgres was converted to use SQL as its language.  To achieve SQL compatibility, instead of renaming the `text` type, a new type `varchar` was added.  But both type use the same C routines internally.

Now, to some degree and in some places, `text` is hardcoded as a default type, in case nothing else can be derived.  Also, most functions are only available as taking a `text` argument or returning `text`.  The two types are binary compatible, so casting is a trivial parse-time operation.  But using `text` is still overall more natural to the system.

But aside from these fine points, there is no noticeable difference.  Use whichever one looks prettier to you. ;-)

Comment: Oh good explanation. I'll use 'text' because I don't care about compatibility which blocks using benefit of specific product. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

See [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4848964/postgresql-difference-between-text-and-varchar-character-varying). The jist is that there is no difference, but specifying a maximum length such as `varchar(n)` is generally *not* in your favor, as it uses more space but doesn't improve performance.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/interactive/datatype-character.html

```
character varying(n), varchar(n)        variable-length with limit
text                                    variable unlimited length
```

text without declared length. There are no performance differences between these two types.

Comment: You can also use varchar without the () part, which will make it unlimited length as well, and thus more or less equivalent with text.